# how to split while with every 4 time using continue

Tags: php

how setting product category wise with limit 4 that's why i have to split while loop with every 4 count

I want something like this:

category name 1

- product 1
- product 2
- product 3
- product 4

category name 2

- product 5
- product 6
- product 7
- product 8

I have tried the following code:

```
$count=0;

while($row_pt = $result_2->fetch_array()) 
{   
    if($count%4==0)
    {
        $output .= '
            <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-3 col-md-3">
                <h3>CATEGORY NAME'.$row_pt['cat_id'].'</h3>
                <div style="border:1px solid #ccc; border-radius:0px; padding:16px; margin-bottom:16px; height:250px;">
                    <img src="image/'. $row_pt['product_image'] .'" alt="" class="img-responsive" >
                    <p align="center"><strong><a href="#">'. $row_pt['product_name'] .'</a></strong></p>
                    Course Code : '. $row_pt['product_name'] .' <br />
                    Course Name : '. $row_pt['product_name'] .' <br />
                </div>
            </div>';
        continue;
    }
    $count++;
}
```

Comment: Please, 1) Format your code, this is a mess, and 2) Provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), the code you provided won't work for anyone else than you.

Comment: please show what output are u getting @tejas

Comment: when i filter by cat_id 2 its not spliting

Comment: If you want `with limit 4`, why does your example have `CAT 1`: 3 products, `CAT 2`: 4 products?

Answer (score 3):

Something like this, so you're wrapping every four products in a `div` by utilising the count variable:

```
$count = 1;
while ($row_pt = $result_2->fetch_array()) 
{
        if (($count - 1) % 4 === 0)
        {
            $output .= '<div class="products">';
        }
        $output .= 
            '<h3>CATEGORY NAME' . $row_pt['cat_id'] . '</h3>
             <div class="product">
                 <img src="image/' . $row_pt['product_image'] . '">
                 <a href="#">' . $row_pt['product_name'] . '</a>
                 <span>Course Code : ' . $row_pt['product_name'] . '</span>
                 <span>Course Name : ' . $row_pt['product_name'] . '</span>
            </div>';
        if ($count % 4 === 0)
        {
            $output .= '</div>';
        }
        $count++;
}
if (($count - 1) % 4 !== 0)
{
    $output .= '</div>';
}
```

Comment: I didn't test this but doesn't this start the div at: `0, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30` and close the divs at: `4, 8, 12, 16, 20, 24, 28 etc.` I'd recommend closing the div when starting a new one, so seperate the first `if statement`. I suggested an edit which shows what I mean.

Comment: Sorry @KerwinSneijders you were right, I've updated my answer

Comment: No worries, can happen. Looks good! Although when ending on a multiply of 4, won't it end with an open `div`? Which could destroy the rest of the page, or am I missing something?

Comment: Or, when not ending on a multiply of 4, it won't close the current `div` either, right?

Comment: Can't see any issues now.